# Why is movie jumpy when I play simultaneously in 2 Cocoa views?

Tags: cocoa, quicktime

I have a Cocoa app that has two views.  Both of these views are a subclass of QTMovieView.  I want to play the same movie in both views (one view is a smaller preview of the larger view).  Right now I'm doing:

```
QTMovie *movie = [[QTMovie alloc] initWithFile:path error:nil];  
[largeView setMovie:movie];  
[smallView setMovie:movie];
```

When I do this the movie is jumpy, it doesn't play smoothly.  If I just set the movie to one or the other it seems to play just fine.  I've tried multiple movies and they all do the same thing.  Any ideas?  Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Do you have a single-core machine or dual/quad core?  Is the CPU pegged?  How fast is your hard drive?  Can you successfully play two movies simultaneously with other software?

Answer (score 0):

You are probably overtaxing a resource - CPU and/or disk I/O are your most likely culprits.

If you open two Quicktime windows can you play the movies at the same time without stuttering?  Is your CPU maxed out (especially on a single-core machine)?  Can you stream from a second source and fix the stuttering?  You might try playing one of the movies off a USB hard drive or flash drive if you don't have two hard drives.

I'm not a quicktime or Objective-C programmer, but I'd start by looking at mirroring the content instead of opening two movie instances.  Maybe you can capture a section of the screen, shrink the contents and dump it to a smaller preview window.

Comment: I have a dual-core macbook pro with 4 GB of RAM that has no problem playing two videos at one time.  When I run both in quicktime or in my program I'm only using about 1/2 of each CPU.

Comment: Are you streaming off the same hard drive?  Even though they are the same movie you might be hitting I/O issues since you have created two separate movie objects.  Disks work best when they can do big linear reads and jumping back a frame for the other movie will wreck that.

Comment: I am reading off the same hard drive, but it is just one movie object that I'm setting for both MovieViews.  For example, if I set the movie for both MovieViews and just tell one view to play, they both show the movie playing, I guess because both MovieViews are connected to the same Movie.